# Could not able to retrieve information from the dynamic object

Tags: c#

Consider the below piece of code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            dynamic val = SearchControlTypes("Panel");
            var result = val.SomeMethod();          

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private static Type SearchControlTypes(string key)
        {
            return SetControlTypes()[key];
        }

        private static Dictionary<String, Type> SetControlTypes()
        {

            var dicControlTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

            dicControlTypes.Add("TextBox", typeof(Panel));
            dicControlTypes.Add("DateTimePicker", typeof(Panel));
            dicControlTypes.Add("RadioButton", typeof(Panel));
            dicControlTypes.Add("Panel", typeof(Panel));
            dicControlTypes.Add("GroupBox", typeof(GroupBox));

            return dicControlTypes;
        }        
    }

    internal class Panel
    {
        public int SomeMethod()
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }

    internal class GroupBox
    {
        public int SomeMethod()
        {
            return 20;
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to retrieve the information from the specific class at

```
var result = val.SomeMethod();
```

**getting exception**

*An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Additional information: 'System.Reflection.TypeInfo' does not contain a definition for 'SomeMethod'*

What is the problem and how to rectify this?

Comment: You aren't adding an instance of `Panel` or `GroupBox`. You're adding the result of the `typeof` operator, which is a `System.Type` that describes a `Panel` or `GroupBox`. Using dynamic is often a bad idea. Much more likely simply sharing a common interface between these classes would be a better design.

Comment: Got it..thanks for that... Activator.CreateInstance(SearchControlTypes("Panel"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create an instance as pointed by @rorry.ap and @mason

```
Activator.CreateInstance(SearchControlTypes("Panel"))
```

Thanks to them.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely destroying the strong typing of C# (and .NET) that keeps you out of trouble like this.  You shouldn't be using `Type` like you are, and you shouldn't be using `dynamic` like you are unless you know more about what you're doing.

The problem is that your `dynamic val = SearchControlTypes("Panel");` is not returning what you think it is, and it's not clear what's going wrong for the reasons I stated above.  Modify your code so you don't use `dynamic`.

Your dictionary `Dictionary<string, Type>();` should not have `Type` for its values; you should use `Dictionary<string, Control>();` instead or whatever the base type is for all your various controls.